# Best way to change this String-line into multiple Int's?

Tags: c#, string

I have some strings that looke like this:

> "97-145, 3-5, 77-87, 5-10"

i need every value (97, 145, 3, 5, 77, 97, 5 and 10) stored in different int variables.

I started by trying to go through the string for each character and search for '-' or ',' but unfortunately this doesn't works for all lines, because some look like this:

> "97, 3, 77-87, 5-10"

so in this case, when i search for the next '-' after i stored the first value (97), it will search until it finds the next '-' character and then stores 87.

is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Can you share your current code? This should be pretty simple using a `List<int>` to store the results but you mention you need it in different variables so it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do it using a Split, assuming its always `-` or `,`:

```
string str = "97-145, 3-5, 77-87, 5-10";
var ints = str.Split(new string[] { "-", "," }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
foreach (int i in ints) Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Which gives:

```
97
145
3
5
77
87
5
10
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zE0LtW

Comment: i tried that, but it gives me a System.FormatException for the var ints = str.Split ... lIne

Comment: Can you give the full error? As you can see in the demo its working, maybe you tried it with a different string?

Comment: i found the issue, my string was like "97-145, 3-5, 77-87, 5-10\""; (with an \" at the end) - now it works fine! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need decimals, you can easily achieve this using `Regex`. Specifically, match `\d+` and that should find all number groups. Then simply parse each group `Int32.Parse` or `Int32.TryParse` and you're done.

Here's a sample of the regex parsing: https://regex101.com/r/YrHtY5/1

Here's a quick code sample:

```
var input = "97-145, 3-5, 77-87, 5-10";
var regex = new Regex("\\d+");
var regexMatches = regex.Matches(input);
var results = new List<int>();
foreach(Match match in regexMatches)
    results.Add(Int32.Parse(match.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I replace `-` by `,` in the string and I split:

```
string s = "97-145, 3-5, 77-87, 5-10";
string[] sArray = s.Replace("-", ",").Split(',');
int[] iArray = Array.ConvertAll(sArray, int.Parse);
foreach (int i in iArray) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

But you can also split with {'-', ','}